# HackerRank Frequency Queries Error Python

Tags: python, dictionary, hashmap

You are given  queries. Each query is of the form two integers described below:

- : Insert x in your data structure.
- : Delete one occurence of y from your data structure, if present.
- : Check if any integer is present whose frequency is exactly . If yes, print 1 else 0.

The queries are given in the form of a 2-D array queries of size q where queries[i][0] contains the operation, and  contains the data element.

Example:
queries = [(1,1), (2,2), (3,2), (1,1), (1,1), (2,1), (3,2))

This would return [0,1]

```
def freqQuery(queries):
    lis = []
    freq = {}
    count = {}
    
    for pair in queries:
        if pair[0] == 1:
            freq[pair[1]] = freq.get(pair[1], 0) + 1
            count[freq[pair[1]]] = count.get(freq[pair[1]], 0) + 1
            count[freq[pair[1]] - 1] = count.get(freq[pair[1]] - 1, 1) - 1
        if pair[0] == 2:
            if pair[1] in freq:
                count[freq[pair[1]]] = count.get(freq[pair[1]], 1) - 1 
                freq[pair[1]] -= 1
                count[freq[pair[1]]] = count.get(freq[pair[1]], 1) + 1 
                if count[freq[pair[1]]] < 0:
                    count[freq[pair[1]]] = 0
        if pair[0] == 3:
            if pair[1] in count:
                if count[pair[1]] > 0:
                    lis.append(1)
                else:
                    lis.append(0)
            else:
                lis.append(0)
                   
    return lis
```

I got 12/15 of the test cases correct, but I can't figure out what is wrong for the last couple of test cases.

Comment: Please provide such a test case, that's giving you an unexpected result or error. Also, the instructions aren't exactly clear: insert, but where? At a given index? Dlete, but from where? Again, from a given index? Please provide an example call with a sensible `queries` - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: "... whose frequency is exactly ."  You didn't show us what the target was, but in any case you're not checking for "exactly" anything.  You're checking for a count greater than zero.

Comment: @Grismar I just added an example, apologies. Insert and delete don't matter where. It can be thought of as a list that contains all the current numbers and we are inserting and removing from this list